# Using PSEXEC returns no output from the remote task

Tags: psexec

I am using psexec to run an exe on a server.
The command runs ok, but there is no output on my local console.

This is the command I am using:

```
psexec.exe \\my-machine ping localhost
```

which results in:

```
PsExec v1.94 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2008 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

ping exited with error code 0.
```

if I try to run this localy however, it works fine

```
psexec.exe \\localhost ping localhost

PsExec v1.94 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2008 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com



Pinging my-machine.mydomain.com [1.1.1.1] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 1.1.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 0ms
ping exited on localhost with error code 0.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that (at least in this case) you need to use the fully qualified machine name when kicking off psexec.
I haven't figured out why this is but it does the trick.

```
psexec.exe \\my-machine.mydomain.com ping localhost
```

and now all the output of the command is returned.

Comment: it doesnt work for me. I tried both with fqn and without.  Is there any other tool different than psexec.exe

Comment: 5 years on I guess things change, although you would think MS would maintain backward compatibility :-)

Answer (score 0):

I already gave three variations for your problem kindly [check this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51147720/5379408).

This will copy the iname.bat file in remote system and execute it and save the result in success.txt inside local machine directory in which we are running PSexec

**PsExec.exe \remote_ip -u Administrator -p test@123 -c -f "iname.bat">success.txt**

this will run test.bat present on remote machine and make Success.txt on remote machine

**PsExec.exe \remote_ip -u Administrator -p test@123 -i cmd  /C "C:\abhi\test.bat > C:\abhi\success.txt"**

this will run test.bat present on remote machine and make Success.txt on localmachine

**PsExec.exe \remote_ip -u Administrator -p test@123 cmd /C "C:\abhi\test.bat">success.txt**

if you want to see output then remove redirection

**PsExec.exe \remote_ip -u Administrator -p test@123 -c -f "iname.bat"**

**PsExec.exe \remote_ip -u Administrator -p test@123 -i cmd  /C "C:\abhi\test.bat**

Comment: Yeah I think 9yrs ago when I asked this question we were doing something similar. it just sucks that you have to work around it like that. Although I found in my case that using the fqdn did the trick.