# PsExec and WindDirStat on a remote system - how to run

Tags: windows, psexec

I'd like to be able to run WinDirStat on a remote machine that I have administrative rights over but it does not work.

This is what I have done:
Run CMD as admin:
`psexe.exe -i -s cmd.exe`

From the new prompt: 
`psexec.exe \\host -u username winddirstate.exe`

I type in my PW and it does not launch

Both running Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

**`Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]
     -a         Separate processors on which the application can run with
                commas where 1 is the lowest numbered CPU. For example,
                to run the application on CPU 2 and CPU 4, enter:
                "-a 2,4"
     -c         Copy the specified program to the remote system for
                execution. If you omit this option the application
                must be in the system path on the remote system.
     -d         Don't wait for process to terminate (non-interactive).
     -e         Does not load the specified account's profile.
     -f         Copy the specified program even if the file already
                exists on the remote system.
     -i         Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the
                specified session on the remote system. If no session is
                specified the process runs in the console session.
     -h         If the target system is Vista or higher, has the process
                run with the account's elevated token, if available.
     -l         Run process as limited user (strips the Administrators group
                and allows only privileges assigned to the Users group).
                On Windows Vista the process runs with Low Integrity.
     -n         Specifies timeout in seconds connecting to remote computers.
     -p         Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this
                you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
     -r         Specifies the name of the remote service to create or interact.
                with.
     -s         Run the remote process in the System account.
     -u         Specifies optional user name for login to remote
                computer.
     -v         Copy the specified file only if it has a higher version number
                or is newer on than the one on the remote system.
     -w         Set the working directory of the process (relative to
                remote computer).
     -x         Display the UI on the Winlogon secure desktop (local system
                only).
     -arm       Specifies the remote computer is of ARM architecture.
     -priority  Specifies -low, -belownormal, -abovenormal, -high or
                -realtime to run the process at a different priority. Use
                -background to run at low memory and I/O priority on Vista.
     computer   Direct PsExec to run the application on the remote
                computer or computers specified. If you omit the computer
                name PsExec runs the application on the local system,
                and if you specify a wildcard (\\*), PsExec runs the
                command on all computers in the current domain.
     @file      PsExec will execute the command on each of the computers listed
                in the file.
     cmd            Name of application to execute.
     arguments  Arguments to pass (note that file paths must be
                absolute paths on the target system).
     -accepteula This flag suppresses the display of the license dialog.
     -nobanner   Do not display the startup banner and copyright message.`**

First you are in Same Directory of Psexec  or set path of PSexec in Environment path then put this command

**psexec.exe \host -u username -p password -s  cmd /C C:\full_remote_path_of_\windirstat.exe**

**OR**

put one bat file inside your remote machine like C:\abc\run.bat and put this code inside it

- echo off
- C:\full_path_of_\windirstat.exe
- echo "Success"

and run command from your local

below command will run that bat file present on remote

**psexec.exe \host -u username -p password -s  cmd /C "C:\remote\run.bat"**

**OR**

there is no need to put run.bat file in remote machine put only on local and then give below command

**psexec.exe \host -u username -p password -s -i -c -f "C:\local\run.bat"**

**OR**

**psexec.exe \host -u username -p password -s -i -c -v "C:\local\run.bat"**

```
          -s ----->as a Administrator
          -i ----->Interactive
          -c ----->copy run.bat to remote
          -f -----> if run.bat already exist on remote Computer
          -v -----> if higher version on local and lower version on remote then it  
                     will copy otherwise not
```

**USING FILE NAME**

If you want to run on many remote machine and all remote machine username and password are same so put one file like host.txt and put all ip's line by line there is no space on starting on line then give below command and it will run serially

**PsExec.exe @C:\full_path\host.txt -c -s -u username -p password run.bat**

**Parallel Running in All Remote Machines **

if you want to run parallel then give one more parameter -d then it will not wait to finish process until it finished and you can use for loop and put PSexec command inside it

**Save Result in some file THREE Variation**

```
                             **First Variation**
```

Below will copy the iname.bat file in remote system and execute it and save the result in success.txt inside local machine directory in which we are running PSexec

**PsExec.exe \remote_ip -u username -p password -c -f "iname.bat">success.txt**

```
                             **Second Variation**
```

below will run test.bat present on remote machine and make Success.txt on localmachine

**PsExec.exe \remote_ip -u username -p passowrd cmd /C "C:\abhi\test.bat">success.txt**

```
                             **Third  Variation**
```

this will run test.bat present on remote machine and make Success.txt on remote machine
**PsExec.exe \remote_ip -u username -p password -i cmd  /C "C:\abhi\test.bat > C:\abhi\success.txt"**