# Azure DevOps is not showing PSExec output in build summary

Tags: command-line, azure-devops, devops, psexec, azure-devops-pipelines

We have a PSExec command to run batch scripts on a remote machine.

When we run it from the machine where the self hosted agent is, it shows the job(batch script) log, on the command window.

But when we run the same command from Azure pipeline via Command Line task, it is not showing the log.

All it shows is

```
cmd exited on NTCUPX01 with error code 0.
```

Is there anyway we can display the output, so that it is useful to anybody who is running the pipeline?

Comment: Do you use the fully qualified machine name when kicking off psexec? Here is a reference [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221741/11508192).  In addition , can you share your command? So that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Here is the command i am using, 

D:\TestData\PSExec  -accepteula \\NT12CAPX -u username -p pwd E:\Jobs\Copy1.bat

Comment: As a suggestion,you can try to `runas /user:domain\administrator "D:\TestData\PSExec -accepteula \\NT12CAPX -u username -p pwd E:\Jobs\Copy1.bat"` . Here is the [reference](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/151081-psexec-returning-error-code-0-but-not-working).

Comment: Thank you @HughLin-MSFT, But it is asking for password which I wouldnt  know. Is there anyother way?